# Trying to make a request to an API with System.Net.Http but getting errors

Tags: c#, .net, http

Here is the code I'd like to run:

```
    public async String products()
    {
        string res = await client.GetStringAsync(apiUrl+"/allItems.php");
        
        return res;
    }
```

But I get an error like this:

> The return type of an async method must be void, Task, Task, a
> task-like type, IAsyncEnumerable, or IAsyncEnumerator
> StripeTerminal
> C:\Users\Foxx\Documents\StripeTerminal\StripeTerminal\Form1.cs

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the line of code you posted. The error must be on another line.

Comment: i made a edit of the full function that i have fornow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you posted says what the issue is.
Take a look at your method signature. It's an async method, returning a string. Should be an async method returning a Task of type string.

Your `res` variable is of type string, that is correct. But an async method should always return a Task, where T is the underlying datatype you wish to return.

Full example is this.

```cs
public async Task<string> products()
{
    string res = await client.GetStringAsync(apiUrl+"/allItems.php");
            
    return res;
}
```